# Forcing a download using PHP

Tags: php

I have PHP issue, I'm trying to force a file download using php

if users click on my link www.site.com/download.php it redirects them to download.php with the following code inside the download.php file

```
    header('Content-Type: application/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=custom_report.csv');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');


    echo readfile('files/csv/custom_report.csv');
```

readfile and fopen however is disabled on the server for security purposes.

Is there any other way I can do this

Comment: Are you sure they are not just disabled for remote access, like http://...?

Comment: I also tried doing this <a href="files/csv/download.php">Download Report <i>(csv file format)</i></a> and still fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [file_get_contents()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)?

Comment: I should have thought about file_get_contents ;-) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If readfile and fopen aren't available, I'd expect all the file I/O fns to be disabled too.

In which case your only option is to provide a hard link to the csv file (but your service provider probably hasn't added the CSV mime mappings)

C.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand your problem is not getting the file to download but rather finding an alternative to readfile/fopen?