# To make html file downloadable

Tags: php, html

i had a html file `"sample.html"` I need to make user to **download** this file by clicking a **button** in a page.

**How to make html file as downloadable using php**

Comment: [happy ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021129/forcing-a-download-using-php) ... please do search first, your question is duplicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply put, you need to read the file, set the correct headers and echo the file.

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=' . $file_name);
header('Content-type: ' . $file_mime);
$file_content = file_get_contents($file_location);
echo $file_content;
```

Link the button to the PHP file, and voila.

Comment: $file_mime is the MIME-type for the corresponding file. The MIME-type of a HTML document is "text/html". 

For Opera compatibility, you should add header('Content-Type: application/octetstream; name=' . $file_name);

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$output_file = "example_name.html";

header('Pragma: no-cache"');
header('Expires: 0'); 
header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT');
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Cache-Control: pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: none');

//This should work for IE & Opera
header('Content-Type: application/octetstream; name="' . $output_file . '"');
//This should work for the rest
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="' . $output_file . '"');

header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $output_file . '"');

include "your_html_file.html";

exit();

?>
```

Comment: Your code wont works in opera and chrome shows a warning before downloading it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use document.documentElement.outerHTML to get the HTML source for the page, then use the FileSystemObject (or some other equivalent api) to save it off to disk. You'll need Low security settings to get this to work without a prompt.

Here is a simple java script (IE specific):

```
function SaveToDisk(sPath)
{
    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var fileDest = fso.CreateTextFile(sPath, true);
    if (fileDest)
    {
       fileDest.Write(document.documentElement.outerHTML);
       fileDest.close();
    }
```

}

Answer (score -1):

you can create a page like this

```
// definisco una variabile con il percorso alla cartella
// in cui sono archiviati i file
$dir = "/root/www/download/";

// Recupero il nome del file dalla querystring
// e lo accodo al percorso della cartella del download
$file = $dir . $_GET['filename'];

// verifico che il file esista
if(!file)
{
  // se non esiste chiudo e stampo un errore
  die("Il file non esiste!");
}else{
  // Se il file esiste...
  // Imposto gli header della pagina per forzare il download del file
  header("Cache-Control: public");
  header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename= " . $file);
  header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
  // Leggo il contenuto del file
  readfile($file);
}
```

then you can call it passing the filename

```
force-download.php?filename=sample.html
```